# Match a word ending with pattern in a sentence

Tags: python, regex

How to find word(S) in a sentence that end with a pattern using regex

I have list of patterns I want to match within a sentence
For example 
my_list = ['one', 'this']

sentence = 'Someone dothis onesome thisis'

Result should return only words that end with items from my_list

['Someone','dothis'] only

since I do not want to match onesome or thisis

Comment: Use the `$` anchor at the end. A nice explanation here: https://javascript.info/regexp-anchors. Simple example: `asdf$` will match strings that end with `asdf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can end your pattern with the word boundary metacharacter `\b`. It will match anything that is not a word character, including the end of the string. So, in that specific case, the pattern would be `(one|this)\b`.

To actually create a regex from your `my_list` variable, assuming that no reserved characters are present, you can do:

```py
import re

def words_end_with(sentence, my_list):
    return re.findall(r"({})\b".format("|".join(my_list)), sentence)
```

If you're using Python 3.6+, you can also use an [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), to do this formatting inside the string itself:

```py
import re

def words_end_with(sentence, my_list):
    return re.findall(fr"({'|'.join(my_list)})\b", sentence)
```

See https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following pattern:

```
\b(\w+(one|this))\b
```

It says match whole words within word boundaries (`\b...\b`), and within whole words match any word character (`\w+`) followed by the literal `one` or `this` (`(one|this)`)

https://regex101.com/r/UzhnSw/1/